# Swift: can't detect hit test on SCNNode? See if vector3 is contained in a node?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, swift4

I am trying to just detect a tap on an SCNNode instantiated in my AR scene. It does not seem to work like SceneKit hit test results here, and I don't have much experience with scene kit.

I just want to detect if the tapped point is contained within any node in the scene, thus detecting a tap on the object. What I have tried from other answers:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

        let results = sceneView.hitTest(touch.location(in: sceneView), types: [ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint])
        guard let hitFeature = results.last else { return }

        let hitTransform = SCNMatrix4.init(hitFeature.worldTransform)

        let hitPosition = SCNVector3Make(hitTransform.m41,
                                         hitTransform.m42,
                                         hitTransform.m43)

        if(theDude.node.boundingBoxContains(point: hitPosition))
        {

        }

    }
```

Nothing gets printed with the last if statement, which I got with:

```
extension SCNNode {
    func boundingBoxContains(point: SCNVector3, in node: SCNNode) -> Bool {
        let localPoint = self.convertPosition(point, from: node)
        return boundingBoxContains(point: localPoint)
    }

    func boundingBoxContains(point: SCNVector3) -> Bool {
        return BoundingBox(self.boundingBox).contains(point)
    }
}

struct BoundingBox {
    let min: SCNVector3
    let max: SCNVector3

    init(_ boundTuple: (min: SCNVector3, max: SCNVector3)) {
        min = boundTuple.min
        max = boundTuple.max
    }

    func contains(_ point: SCNVector3) -> Bool {
        let contains =
            min.x <= point.x &&
                min.y <= point.y &&
                min.z <= point.z &&

                max.x > point.x &&
                max.y > point.y &&
                max.z > point.z

        return contains
    }
}
```

And the `ARHitTestResult` doesn't contain nodes. What can I do to detect a tap on a node in an ARScene?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you're working with `ARSCNView`, there are two kinds of hit testing you can do, and they use entirely separate code paths.

- Use the ARKit method [`hitTest(_:types:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest) if you want to hit test *against the real world* (or at least, against ARKit's estimate of where real-world features are). This returns `ARHitTestResult` objects, which tell you about real-world features like detected planes. In other words, use this method if you want to find a real object that anyone can see and touch without a device — like the table you're pointing your device at.
- Use the SceneKit method [`hitTest(_:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest) if you want to hit test *against SceneKit content*; that is, to search for virtual 3D objects you've placed in the AR scene. This returns [`SCNHitTestResult`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult) objects, which tell you about things like nodes and geometry. Use this method if you want to find SceneKit nodes, the model (geometry) in a node, or the specific point on the geometry at a tap location.

In both cases the 3D position found by a hit test is the same, because `ARSCNView` makes sure that the virtual "world coordinates" space matches real-world space.

It looks like you're using the former but expecting the latter. When you do a SceneKit hit test, you get results if and only if there's a node under the hit test point — you don't need any kind of bounding box test because it's already being done for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you, still a bit unclear here though. the nodes are placed in the "actual world" at the position of hitPosition originally, so I think I want ARKit's hit test. Can you provide an example of using ARHitTestResult to tell if there's a node there?

Comment: ARHitTestResult just returns a vector so thats why I tried to use the bounding box of the node

Comment: You don't place SceneKit nodes in the "actual world". At least, not without a fair bit of extra software and a 3D printer. With `ARSCNView`, SceneKit node positions and sizes are in "actual world" measurements, though, so you can still use SceneKit methods to find them. Trying instead to work back from just a vector (obtained via `ARHitTestResult`) to a node is just writing (and debugging and maintaining) more code than you need to. Edited answer to clarify.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. So I need to use the SceneKit NOT Ar hit test function? And that will return nodes? Can you write out how you would do it - I kept getting errors about needing to specify the kind of Result when I tried the SceneKit hit test

Comment: There are lots of [questions and answers about SceneKit hit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscenekit%5D+hit+test) already, which are equally valid for SceneKit-with-ARKit.

Comment: @rickster How to ignore hittest in  `ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints`   ?

Comment: Eh? Showing feature points doesn't have anything to do with hit testing. Clarify your question and post it as a question (not a comment), perhaps?

Answer (score 10):

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTap(rec:)))
```

Inside your handleTap method on `state .ended`:

```
@objc func handleTap(rec: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if rec.state == .ended {
        let location: CGPoint = rec.location(in: sceneView)
        let hits = self.sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
        if let tappednode = hits.first?.node {
            //do something with tapped object
        }
    }
}
```